# What is "ブチャイク"?

Tags: etymology, slang

ブチャイク

All I know is it's referring to someone's "looks" or appearance, and is not flattering. I suspect this is simply one of those "modern" Japanese slang phrases popular among young people that's just a result of an intentional abuse/twisting of the original language. I'd like to know what it means, where it comes from, etc.

---

I still have some questions.

I know of "不細工", but what is the connection between "ぶちゃいく" and "ぶさいく"?

Also, while I can guess the meaning of "ブスカワ", please explain it anyway. If I'm not mistaken, this is also slang, and it's not a good idea to answer a question about slang with slang. Please use standardized language to answer. I don't have problem reading Japanese up to a level of the standard news article, so linking to a pure Japanese page for reference is fine, so long as the explanation that pertains to this question is not filled with slang or somesuch. (Although for the benefit of anyone else reading this question, it might be best to also provide a brief English explanation to accompany it.)

Answer (score 4):

不細工{ぶさいく} "not well crafted (face), not handsome/beautiful"

Comment: However, ブチャイク has a ブスカワ image whereas 不細工 does not.